# Which is Faster in jquery?

Tags: jquery, performance, jquery-ui

In below example there is two button set1 and set2 and I am add `onclick` attribute on both button `fn_clearset1`, `fn_clearset2`.

which button is clear value of textbox faster using jquery `val()` method?

```
     <!*emphasized text*doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
       //forclearvalue of textboxes
        function fn_clearset1() {
            $('#txt1').val('');
            $('#txt2').val('');
            $('#txt3').val('');
            $('#txt4').val('');
            $('#txt5').val('');
            $('#txt6').val('');
            $('#txt7').val('');
            $('#txt8').val('');
            $('#txt9').val('');
            $('#txt10').val('');
        }
        function fn_clearset2() {
            $('#txt11,#txt12,#txt13,#txt14,#txt15,#txt16,#txt17,#txt18,#txt19,#txt20').val('');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt1" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt2" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt3" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt4" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt5" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt6" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt7" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt8" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt9" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt10" /><br />

    <input type="button" name="name" value="ClearSet1" onclick="fn_clearset1()" /><br />

    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt11" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt12" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt13" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt14" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt15" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt16" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt17" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt18" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt19" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="text" value="123" id="txt20" /><br />
    <input type="button" name="name" value="ClearSet2" onclick="fn_clearset2()" /><br />


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your tests, which was faster? How much does the performance really matter here?

Comment: Do you really need all these IDs? What about using a common class? Or even better, group inputs in form and use button of type `reset`. This way, you don't need any js/jq and for sure it would be faster...

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, the fastest solution by far are your comma seperated `ids`. But it's not very maintainable. I would prefer a `class` selector, which is the second fastest.

**[Benchmark results.](https://jsfiddle.net/k82wLLae/2/)**

Comment: When you got an answer for your question, you should post it here, and not just say *i got it*, @AnkitBhanderi.